# memory for UITableViewCell's UIImage not freed after segue back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, xcode6

In my app I segue to a table view controller with a`UIImageView` in each of its cells loaded with some **local** image file. but the problem is when the back button in the navigation bar is pressed the memory allocated for the Image Views is not freed and causes memory leak:

this is the memory log as I segue back and forth to the my table View:
[image]

this is the `prepareForSegue` that leads to the table view controller that I'm talking about:

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    if (indexPath) {
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            //a section is selected

            if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[SectionTableViewController class]]) {
                 NSString *jsonFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"s%ld", (long)indexPath.row + 1] ofType:@"json"];
                 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonFilePath];
                 NSDictionary *sectionData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
                 SectionTableViewController *stvc = (SectionTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
                 stvc.firstPrb = [sectionData objectForKey:@"firstPrb"];
                 stvc.lastPrb = [sectionData objectForKey:@"lastPrb"];
                 stvc.sectionTitle = [sectionData objectForKey:@"sectionTitle"];
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

and this is the code for generating the cells in the mentioned table view controller:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ProverbCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *jsonFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", self.firstProverb.intValue + indexPath.row] ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonFilePath];
    NSDictionary *proverbData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    cell.textLabel.text = [proverbData objectForKey:@"proverb"];
    @autoreleasepool {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld.jpg", self.firstProverb.intValue + indexPath.row]];
    }

    return cell;
    }
```

now the question is: shouldn't the memory be released after the segue back button is clicked?! there are no strong pointers to the Image Views or anything else...

Comment: `[UIImage imageNamed:]` will cache the `UIImage`, if you don't need cache it, use `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`. You can also cache the UIImage yourself use NSMutableDictionary, then release the NSMutableDictionary at property time.

Comment: Is this on the device or simulator?

Comment: @KudoCC great answer! that was actually my problem I used `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` instead of `[UIImage imageNamed:]` and the images are not cached anymore. thanks a lot

Comment: @duci9y on simulator.

Comment: @KudoCC please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` will cache the UIImage, if you don't need cache it, use `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`.

You can also cache the UIImage yourself use `NSMutableDictionary`, then release the `NSMutableDictionary` at property time.